# What is the value of $a+b+c+d$ with following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> $$
> \begin{split}
> a^2 &+b   &+c   &+d&=10\\
> a   &+b^2 &+c   &+d&=12\\
> a   &+b   &+c^2 &+d&=16\\
> a   &+b   &+c   &+d^2&=22\\
> a   &+b   &+c   &+d&=?
> \end{split}
> $$

By adding these equations I get that $3(a+b+c+d)=60-(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)$.

So can I get some hint that how can I get the value of $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)$ (or relate it with the equation) or my approach is wrong and there are some easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: Just solve the equations to get $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4$. Hence sum=10. Or do you also want non-integral solutions?

Comment: $(a + b + c + d)^2 = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) + 2(ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd)$, although I can't see how you could use this

Comment: @Jacob Frye: Are $a,b,c,d$ integers? Are you looking for non-integer solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $a^2 + b + c + d = 10$ we get $d = 10 - a^2 - b - c$. Plugging into the other three equations, we get:

1. $b^2 - a^2 + a - b = 2$
2. $c^2 - a^2 + a - c = 6$
3. $a^4 + 2a^2b + 2a^2c - 20a^2 + b^2 + 2bc + c^2 + a - 19b - 19c + 78 = 0$

We now make a change of variables $A = 2a - 1$, $B = 2b - 1$, $C = 2c - 1$, and get:

4. $B^2 = A^2 + 8$
5. $C^2 = A^2 + 24$
6. $A^4 + 4A^3 + 4A^2B + 4A^2C - 66A^2 + 8AB + 4B^2 + 8AC + 8BC + 4C^2 - 132A - 132B - 132C + 897 = 0$

Let $f(A, B, C)$ be the polynomial on the left hand side of 6. We then have $f(A, B, C)f(A, -B, C)f(A, B, -C)f(A, -B, -C) = 0$. Expanding this, and plugging in 4 and 5, we get a polynomial in $A$:

7. $A^{16} + 16A^{15} - 200A^{14} - 3824A^{13} + 15260A^{12} + 369616A^{11} - 595832A^{10} - 18781488A^9 + 15058246A^8 + 539299632A^7 - 340342648A^6 - 8627434960A^5 + 6527845276A^4 + 68777654512A^3 - 66678776008A^2 - 190224765456A + 190030457857
   =0$

This polynomial has only one root in $\Bbb Q$, but has all $16$ simple roots in $\Bbb R$. These are:

\begin{eqnarray*}A &=& -11.4538743253946,\\
&&-8.60113697282605,\\
&&-8.34595743762429,\\
&&-7.96349902754117,\\
&&-5.88026229356758,\\
&&-5.34761209324886,\\
&&-4.81524129575445,\\
&&-2.22253720582883,\\
&&1,\\
&&2.95891204052723,\\
&&3.62156418653849,\\
&&4.21059576045945,\\
&&5.60461219532045,\\
&&6.08827822184500,\\
&&6.41671529164311,\\
&&8.72944295545209.\end{eqnarray*}

We may then obtain the corresponding values of $a, b, c, d$. The complete list of solutions is:

\begin{eqnarray*}(a, b, c, d) &= &(-5.2269, -5.3990, -5.7288, -6.1931),\\
&&(-3.8006, 5.0271, -4.4492, -5.0222),\\
&&(-3.6730, -3.9061, 5.3388, -4.9234),\\
&&(-3.4818, -3.7254, -4.1749, 5.7777),\\
&&(-2.4401, 3.7626, 4.3268, -4.0436),\\
&&(-2.1738, 3.5248, -3.1262, 4.8760),\\
&&(-1.9076, -2.2922, 3.9346, 4.7186),\\
&&(-0.6113, 2.2986, 3.1898, 4.1380),\\
&&(1, 2, 3, 4),\\
&&(1.9795, -1.5467, 3.3616, 4.2668),\\
&&(2.3108, 2.7976, -2.5461, 4.4088),\\
&&(2.6053, 3.0362, 3.7299, -3.5537),\\
&&(3.3023, -2.6389, -3.2220, 4.9557),\\
&&(3.5441, -2.8566, 4.4073, -4.1116),\\
&&(3.7084, 4.0062, -3.5365, -4.2216),\\
&&(4.8647, -4.0881, -4.5051, -5.0723).\end{eqnarray*}

And these corresponds to $16$ different possibilities of $a + b + c + d$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
a + b + c + d &=& -22.5478092654833,\\
&&-8.24488930632880,\\
&&-7.16375138765904,\\
&&-5.60432919041228,\\
&&1.60562883971184,\\
&&3.10076122503463,\\
&&4.45336281591524,\\
&&9.01508209217664,\\
&&10,\\
&&8.06120988410575,\\
&&6.97106821069546,\\
&&5.81772083550022,\\
&&2.39708053501633,\\
&&0.983217073351971,\\
&&-0.0435587835016298,\\
&&-8.80079357812302.\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

Subtract the first equation from the second to get $b^2 + a - a^2 - b = 2$, which becomes $2 = (b - a)(b + a - 1)$.

Assuming that $a,b,c,d$ are all positive integers, then $b - a = 1$ and $b + a - 1 = 2$ OR $b - a = 2$ and $b + a - 1 = 1$. The restriction that all four numbers are positive integers gives $a = 1$ and $b = 2$.

Substituting these values into the first equation gives $c + d = 7$ and into the fourth equation gives $c + d^2 = 19$. Solving simultaneously gives $c = 3, d = 4$.

$\therefore a + b + c + d = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10$

Comment: It's not mentioned anywhere in the queston that $a, b, c, d$ are all positive integers.